# Okta JWT Verifier is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, okta

I want to verify the OKTA Access Token.
I created a simple use-case in nodejs, but I get permission error and I didn't find any solution to resolve this issue.
Here is my code:

```
const OktaJwtVerifier = require('@okta/jwt-verifier');
const issuer = '{{url}}';
const cid = '{{clientid}}'

const oktaJwtVerifier = new OktaJwtVerifier({
  issuer: `http://${issuer}.com/oauth2/default`,
  assertClaims: {
    cid
  }
})

oktaJwtVerifier.verifyAccessToken("accesstoken")
  .then(jwt => {
    // the token is valid
    console.log(jwt.claims);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(JSON.stingify(err))
  });
```

And I get this error:

> name: 'JwksError',
>        message:
>         { errorCode: 'E0000006',
>           errorSummary: 'You do not have permission to perform the requested action',
>           errorLink: 'E0000006',
>           errorId: 'oaezeHaXzOCS9m4D5C5P9WnZA',
>           errorCauses: [] } } }

I checked the [jwt-verifier](https://github.com/okta/okta-oidc-js/tree/master/packages/jwt-verifier) github page and I think it should work.

Comment: have you read https://support.okta.com/help/answers?id=906F0000000blRNIAY

Comment: I don't use AD, I want to use the default auth server.

Comment: fair enough ... seems like it's a permission error, not sure you've given nearly enough information (which is understandable given the nature of the question)

Comment: I have a valid access token in client side, but I need to verify the request in resource server.. Should I set something in okta? (I didn't find something in docs..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "default" authorization server also need API Access Management feature flag enabled. Do you have API Access management?

to check: 
Go to Okta dashboard > security > API > check if you have tab named "Authorization servers" beside the "token" tab.

If you don't:

1. If your org. is a preview org. email developers@okta.com with your org. URL and they will enable it

   2. If your org is not preview, you have to buy it.
   3. alternatively, you can use Okta itself as an authorization server -> so the issuer would be "issuer: `http://${issuer}.com`" not "issuer: `http://${issuer}.com/oauth2/default`"

If last one is the case: 
you CAN NOT validate the token locally. 
However, you can send the token to /introspect endpoint to be validated OR request more information with the token from /userinfo

You can get more info. about above from developers.okta.com

Comment: You're right, the default auth server isn't enable on my account. Thank you!